# Unable to fix java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found. What should I do?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

1. When I first got this error while deploying a server("run on server"), I searched on web and deleted the tomcat(v9.0) from servers view and removed it from server runtime environment window and then added it once again. Now I could start the server without any errors.
2. But during this all my previous projects which were running fine showed error as all the imports of servlet api were not working. So I manually added *server runtime library* to project's build path(in classpath) after which import problem is solved but the error symbol is not going away.
3. Now whenever I try to deploy these projects I get the previous *Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.* error until I repeat the step 1.

**This is console log:**

```java
> Aug 28, 2022 1:44:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\espanso;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.]
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-6198"]
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [602] milliseconds
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@76f7d241]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@76f7d241]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1469)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1477)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    ... 42 more

Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@76f7d241]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@76f7d241]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1469)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1477)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    ... 42 more

Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@76f7d241]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@76f7d241]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1469)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1477)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    ... 42 more

Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-6198"]
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Aug 28, 2022 1:44:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-6198"]
```

**This is my web.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>StudentHub With Css</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is that the *entire* log output?

Comment: I thought it would be too long. So I copied only a part of the console log.

Comment: @novice.subham So there are more `Caused by: ...` that you excluded and which might telling the root cause? Are you sure that it is not caused by the Java version you use to run it (for example, Java 17 is more restrictive than older versions which might cause issues with old libraries that are not ready for Java 17).

Comment: @howlger This is the error I am getting when I first launch the faulty project. It somehow messes the tomcat completely and tomcat doesn't start after that until I delete and re-add it. With other projects everything is working fine. I have also updated my post with complete console log.

Comment: Your Java version has some issue reading a jar file. Which one it doesn't say, but I'd suggest redownloading Tomcat instead of removing and readding the same runtime to the Server Runtimes list.